# Count entries of mutliple dataframe columns outside values from second dataframe rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm having two dataframes dfSpecs and dfData.
dfSpecs contains the spec limits for parameter columns in dfData. (LSL = lower spec limit, USL = upper spec limit)
The parameter rows in dfSpecs are not necessarily in the same order as the parameter columns in dfData.

```
dfSpecs = pd.DataFrame(
  {'param': ['parameter1', 'parameter2', 'parameter3'], 
  'LSL': [0, 10, 200], 
  'USL': [1, 20, 300]}
)
print(dfSpecs)
Output:
   param       LSL  USL
0  parameter1    0    1
1  parameter2   10   20
2  parameter3  200  300
```

```
dfData = pd.DataFrame(
  {'id': ['foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar'], 
  'x': [1, 1, 1, 1], 
  'y': [1, 2, 1, 2],
  'parameter1': [0.5, 0.6, 1.8, 0.4],
  'parameter2': [12, 14, 21, 15],
  'parameter3': [199, 301, 256, 234]}
)
print(dfData)
Output:
    id  x  y  parameter1  parameter2  parameter3
0  foo  1  1         0.5          12         199
1  foo  1  2         0.6          14         301
2  bar  1  1         1.8          21         256
3  bar  1  2         0.4          15         234
```

Now I want to get a new dataframe containing the count of rows outside the spec limits for parameter and id.

The expected output looks as follows:

```
    id       param  fail_count
0  foo  parameter1           0
1  foo  parameter2           0
2  foo  parameter3           2
3  bar  parameter1           1
4  bar  parameter2           1
5  bar  parameter3           0
```

The following code works, but is very slow (up to several minutes, depending on the dataframe size):

```
fails=[]
for id, df in dfData.groupby('id'):
    for i, spec in dfSpecs.iterrows():
        fail_count = len(df[spec['param']].loc[(df[spec['param']]<spec['LSL']) | (df[spec['param']]>spec['USL'])])
        fails.append([id, spec['param'], fail_count])
dfFails = pd.DataFrame(fails, columns=['id','parameter','fail_count'])
```

**Is there a simpler, faster way how to achieve this?**
I suppose there is better ways in pandas.

Edit: rephrasing and adding example output

Comment: what you expect would be more explicit if you provided a complete (but minimal) example, without `...` and the expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I came up with my own working solution, using the `gt` and `lt`functions of pandas. First I loop over the `dfData` dataframe grouped by the id columns. Then I just select the columns of interest (here manually, but can be done with a `.loc[]` on the real `dfSpecs` dataset) from `dfData`) and use the `gt` and `lt`functions on a series of `dfSpecs['USL']`and `dfSpecs['LSL']` with `'param'`in the index and `sum` up the result. This gives a `pd.Series` without the `id` columns, so I need to concat them manually, and `ffill()` them. The first row contains `id` and `NaN` so I drop the row. Since the parameter is still in the index, I reset the index to get `param` back into the dataframe.
Of course, I have to `concat` the results from each loop cycle.
And in the end I rename the columns, since they don't have reasonable names after the procedure.

```
dfResult = pd.DataFrame()
for id, df in dfData.groupby(['id']):
    fails = df[['parameter1', 'parameter2', 'parameter3']].gt(dfSpecs.set_index('param')['USL']).sum()+
            df[['parameter1', 'parameter2', 'parameter3']].lt(dfSpecs.set_index('param')['LSL']).sum()
    fails = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'id':[id]}),fails],axis=1,ignore_index=True).ffill().reset_index().drop(0)
    dfResult = pd.concat([dfResult,fails])
dfResult = dfResult.rename(columns={'index':'param',0:'id',1:'fail_count'}).reset_index(drop=True)

print(dfResult)

|    | param      | id   |   fail_count |
|---:|:-----------|:-----|-------------:|
|  0 | parameter1 | bar  |            1 |
|  1 | parameter2 | bar  |            1 |
|  2 | parameter3 | bar  |            0 |
|  3 | parameter1 | foo  |            0 |
|  4 | parameter2 | foo  |            0 |
|  5 | parameter3 | foo  |            2 |
```

**Update 2023-01-19:** in the end it turned out, that I had some redundant lines in the dfSpecs dataset, leading to unnecessary looping in the code of the question post, plus I was missing some output data in the code of this post. After adapting the code, so that the input and output are exactly the same for the code in the initial post and this post, the performance difference is not so large. The code from in the question took `7.7s` on my dataset. The code in this post takes `3.6s`. But still more than `50% improvement`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the response, based on your edits I would suggest the following:

```
# Create an empty dataframe with the columns 'id', 'param', and 'fail_count'
dfResults = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id', 'param', 'fail_count'])

# Get a list of unique ids in the 'dfData' dataframe
unique_ids = dfData['id'].unique()

# Iterate through the unique ids
for id in unique_ids:
    # Filter the 'dfData' dataframe for the current id
    df_id = dfData[dfData['id'] == id]
    
    # Get a list of unique parameters in the filtered dataframe
    unique_params = df_id.columns.difference(['id', 'x', 'y'])
    
    # Iterate through the unique parameters
    for param in unique_params:
        # Get the LSL and USL values for the current parameter
        LSL = dfSpecs[dfSpecs['param'] == param]['LSL'].values[0]
        USL = dfSpecs[dfSpecs['param'] == param]['USL'].values[0]
        
        # Calculate the number of failures for the current parameter and id
        fail_count = df_id[(df_id[param] < LSL) | (df_id[param] > USL)].shape[0]
        
        # Append the current id, parameter, and fail_count to the 'dfResults' dataframe
        dfResults = dfResults.append({'id': id, 'param': param, 'fail_count': fail_count}, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: There is not a single 'param' column in dfData to merge on, but several parameter columns holding the data. The columns names of dfData can be found in the 'param' column of dfSpecs.
I just reworked the original post. Could you please have a look again?

Comment: @dogfrog I have changed the response based on your worked post, please check if it works

Comment: The code uses for loop and dataframe append function to add the results to a new dataframe, while your code uses the groupby() and iterrows() function to create a new dataframe from a list.

Im not sure what the difference in speed will be. You will need to check this

Comment: Thanks Marcelle de Jager. The code works on the sample dataset I'v given. I haven't yet tried it out on my real dataset,since I'd need to rewrite the code a bit. However, I'm wondering if the code can be much faster, since it is also two nested loops (same as in my code). I'll try it out and give feedback (probably tomorrow)

Comment: I checked the code. What I didn't mention in my original post is that I have several 3 id columns. Using the .unique() approach, I'd need even more nested loops, so better to go for the for .groupby() approach. However, I tried your solution changing the unique() to groupby(), but unfortunately it's not faster. Thanks though. In the meantime I came up with another solution. Will post soon.

Comment: Hi Marcelle, I see this is one of your first answers. Great! May I suggest, that instead of just posting code which hopefully solves the problem, you also try to at least briefly explain in writing what the key steps to the solution were? It helps people with different background to make this answer accessible. [btw. I have not checked if your answer is actually correct, but this comment applies for all your future answers as well.]

Answer (score 0):

First you can [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) the `dfData` dataframe and then use `dfSpecs` as a look up for left, right to use with [`pd.Series.between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html), in a [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) and assign that as a new column `fail_count` with [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and then [`groupby.sum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) with `id`, `param` to get count.

```
specs = dfSpecs.set_index("param")
t = dfData.melt(
    value_vars=["parameter1", "parameter2", "parameter3"],
    id_vars=["id"],
    var_name="param"
)
out = t.assign(
    fail_count=t.groupby(["param"])["value"].transform(
        lambda x: ~x.between(specs.loc[x.name, "LSL"], specs.loc[x.name, "USL"])
    )
).groupby(["id", "param"])["fail_count"].sum().reset_index()

print(out)

    id       param  fail_count
0  bar  parameter1           1
1  bar  parameter2           1
2  bar  parameter3           0
3  foo  parameter1           0
4  foo  parameter2           0
5  foo  parameter3           2
```

**OR** you can do ( I feel its more efficient compared to above ):

```
specs = dfSpecs.set_index('param')
param_cols = dfData.filter(regex="parameter").columns.tolist()
t = (
    dfData[param_cols]
    .apply(lambda x: ~x.between(specs.loc[x.name, "LSL"], specs.loc[x.name, "USL"]))
    .assign(id=dfData["id"])
)
out = (
    t.melt(
        value_vars=param_cols, id_vars=["id"], var_name="param", value_name="fail_count"
    )
    .groupby(["id", "param"])
    .sum().reset_index()
)
```

**OR** if you think melt is slow you can try stack although I doubt much of a difference.

```
out = (
    t.set_index("id")
    .rename_axis("param", axis=1)
    .stack()
    .groupby(level=[0, 1])
    .sum()
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={0: "fail_count"})
)
```

Comment: It works perfectly for the minimal example I posted above, but using your code always throws an error when I use it on my real dataframe. Anyhow, only the melting takes twice as long as my new approach. The melted dataframe has 100 million lines

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Finally I got your code working. Due to I have several id columns, with basically redundant param, LSL, USL entries in dfSpecs, I had to adapt the loc[] to loc[].values[0]. Unfortunately the procedure is still quite slow. Since I have already a solution working, I'll stop to further investigate your code.